Scaling all features proportionally within layer in QGIS
In QGIS I've imported several layers from a fantasy map generator, all at the same scale / CRS. However, the final one appears to be smaller in extent. The proportions are correct, but it's somehow scaled down in the export/import process.
I've searched for and tried various resizing, scaling, vtransform processes, but nothing's quite getting the result I need. I want the extent of this layer to match that of the map canvas.
Any advice?


Have you tried the "Affine transform" tool based on the x/y-axis-proportion between the extent length/width of your original and other layers?

You wan to georeference the points layer.
In QGIS this can be done for both vector and raster data using the georeferencer.
The tool is quite well documented in the official documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/georeferencer.html
But you create control points between the layer you are trying to scale and the other layer and it does the scaling.

Thanks. I’ll give that a go.
